# import doesn't work when importing old function

Tags: python-3.x

```
def isprime(n):
    for x in range(2, int(n/2+1)):
        if not n % x:
            return False

def primesto(n):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if isprime(x):
            print(x)

import prime
```

It gives me an error while importing:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prime'
```

I want to import the old functions (`primesto`) and (`isprime`).

Does this mean that it will work in another file if I saved that program?

Comment: What error? Please give a [mcve]. Did this work in a previous version? Which?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prime'

Comment: Well it's not a standard library module. Where did you expect it to come from?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand

Comment: Presumably you meant `import prime` to give you access to something. What? From where?

Comment: I want to import the old functions (primesto) and (isprime)

Comment: I think you have this backwards; `import` brings things *into* the current file (well, sort of...); you have defined those functions in the current file, so you don't need to import anything.

Comment: Then you should talk to them, because there's clearly some context I don't have.

Comment: Is this mean that it will work in another file if I saved that program? 
Sorry I am new in python

Comment: it's an online course and the instructor doesn't reply to anyone 
I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

To use the two functions you defined:

```
def isprime(n):
    for x in range(2, int(n/2+1)):
        if not n % x:
            return False

def primesto(n):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if isprime(x):
            print(x)
```

You can either call them in the same file:

```
isprime(3)
```

Or, if you want to use the functions in *another file* you should import that file. Assuming you saved the two functions in a file called `prime.py`, then in another file you can do:

```
import prime
# ...
prime.isprime(3)
```

Or you can only import the function `isprime` for example:

```
from prime import isprime 
# ...
isprime(3)
```

I hope it is more clear now, you can find more information in the [documentation about importing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Comment: `import isprime from prime` should be `from prime import isprime`. The grammar: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement doesn't permit `import`-`from`.